# Bluetooth iOS printing on Bixolon SPP-R200II

Tags: ios, printing, bluetooth, bixolon-printer

We are users of POS printer Bixolon SPP-R200II which we use for realisation of one of our projects. In the specification of this model it is listed that printer supports printing on iOS devices (iPhone & iPad) but until now we have not succeeded to achieve that. We switch the printer onto iOS mode with a required combination we fonud in official documentation and we got confirmation message. Then we connected to the printer from bluetooth interface inside iPhone Settings app.

After that we tryed to print on this device in various ways - using official test app from AppStore (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bixolon-printer-utility/id647125968?mt=8) and using official Bixolon SDK (http://www.bixolon.com/upload/download/software_all_bixolon_printer_sdk_for_ios_v3.1.8.zip) but unfortunately we havent managed to get any result. In this sample apps printer was not even listed as a possible connection point.

Can you direct us in any way to get the printing on iOS devices working? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same problem and after contacting technical support, concluded that the model we have is not compatible with iOS, the part number must be 3 letters i, for example SPP-R200IIIK/USA. After making the switch equipment provider, everything works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, we had that problem too. We also figure it out after contacting technical support. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

To connect to the SPP-R200II you need to enable MFi Mode for the printer.

1. Turn on printer
2. Open the cover and press the power button and paper feed button at the same time for 2 seconds
3. Close the cover when the buzzer sounds

The printer should now print "iOS mode enable!!" [sic]. If not, you just turned off MFi mode and need to repeat the steps to turn it on again.

Unfortunately the sample application distributed with the Bixolon SDK 3.1.8 is broken and when you press "Lookup/Targeting" nothing will happen. To fix it add this line to didFindPrinter in ViewController.h:

```
_uiTextFieldAddress.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BT_%@", printer.macAddress];
```

It should now be possible to connect the printer simply by pressing "Lookup/Targeting" and then "Connect" when you se the Bluetooth address in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Is the printer paired with the device in settings? It must be paired before the application can interact with it.